# After AJAX-Post the File is not downloading

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, ajax

If i go directly to the URL from my Program which generates a PDF i get a direct Download.

```
 public void Download(byte[] file)
{

    try
    {
        MemoryStream mstream = new MemoryStream(file);
        long dataLengthToRead = mstream.Length;
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.BufferOutput = true;
        Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf"; /// if it is text or xml
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "Test.pdf");
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", dataLengthToRead.ToString());
        mstream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.Close();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush(); // Sends all currently buffered output to the client.
        HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = true;  // Gets or sets a value indicating whether to send HTTP content to the client.
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest(); // Causes ASP.NET to bypass all events and filtering in the HTTP pipeline chain of execution and directly execute the EndRequest event.
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
}
```

But if i do a POST with my JSON to the URL this Method doesnt give me a direct-Download.

The POST with the JSON-String is successfull. But the download doesn't start after the Ajax-Call. My Program is a simple ASPX-Website which load all Data and functions with the Page_Load-Event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go about this is to hit the ajax POST and on success of the call return the file download link and then redirect the browser to that link to download the file like so:

```
            $.ajax({
                url: "THE_POST_URL",
                method: 'POST',
                success: function (response) { //return the download link
                     window.location.href = response;
                },
                error: function (e) {
                },
            });
```

Comment: Very helpful answer! But can i change it to a direct download instead of open the PDF in my Browser?

Comment: @PeterH unfortunately. you cannot directly download a file use AJAX.

Comment: @PeterH you can check out http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/

Comment: @ShaktiPhartiyal what is the response will be back??!

Comment: @MahmodAbuJehad the response will be the one that will come from the api / url, in this specific case it should be the download link